# Asp.net mvc4 jqueryGrid not show up

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I'm triying to implement jquerygrid plugin into my asp.net mvc4 application. But im in stuck. Need your help. Wrote all code and i got only white page with json data. I dont know why.

My view is shown below:

```
@model Fancy.Management.Model.User.IndexModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        url:'@Html.Action("Index","User")',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames:['Id','Votes','Title'],
        colModel :[
          {name:'Id', index:'Id', width:40, align:'left' },
          {name:'Votes', index:'Votes', width:40, align:'left' },
          {name:'Title', index:'Title', width:200, align:'left'}],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum:10,
        rowList:[5,10,20,50],
        sortname: 'Id',
        sortorder: "desc",
        viewrecords: true,
        imgpath: '/scripts/themes/coffee/images',
        caption: 'My first grid'
    }); 
}); 
</script>

<table id="list" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
<div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>
```

And my action method is shown below:

```
  public ActionResult Index(string sidx, string sord, int? page, int? rows)
    {
        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = 1,
            page = 1,
            records = 3,
            rows = new[]{
     new{Id=1,cell=new[] {"1","-7","Is this good question?"}},
     new{Id=2,cell=new[] {"2","15","Is this really?"}},
     new{Id=3,cell=new[] {"3","23","Why is the sky blue?"}}
     }
        };
        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Exception that i got is shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Index` action isn't returning a `View`, so the View you've created never gets used.  The action is only returning JSON data:

```
return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Which is why you're seeing JSON data in the browser when you request the `Index` action.

Instead, you need to return a view (with an instance of `IndexModel`, which you don't seem to have in the code):

```
return View(someInstanceOfIndexModel);
```

The jqGrid is then going to need to use a *different* action to get its JSON data, since the AJAX request is a different request than the one which initially loads the page.  Something like this:

```
url:'@Html.Action("IndexData","User")',
```

The action method you *currently* have for `Index` would then be renamed to something like `IndexData` (using the sample above) to handle the AJAX request.

Ultimately, the order of operations here would be:

1. Browser requests `Index`.
2. `Index` returns a `View` (populated by any necessary view model).
3. Since the view in question contains JavaScript code, that code will be executed by the browser.
4. The JavaScript code makes a second request to another action (I called it `IndexData`, but you can call it whatever you want).
5. That other action returns `Json` with the data needed by the grid.
6. The client-side JavaScript code receives the data and populates the grid.